# Using regex pattern in gsub r

Tags: r, regex

Hello I hve a df such as

```
COL1         
BLOC1.1_3_10-355(+)Sp_3
BLOC2.1_10-355(-)SSp_4
BLOC3.1_10-355(+)SP_32
BLOC1_3_10-355(+)SP4_2
```

How can I find a regex that can replace the `_`  here >  `_[Number]-[Number](`
by

```
:[Number]-[Number](
```

Here I should get

```
COL1         
BLOC1.1_3:10-355(+)Sp_3
BLOC2.1:10-355(-)SSp_4
BLOC3.1:10-355(+)SP_32
BLOC1_3:10-355(+)SP4_2
```

I tried : `gsub("_[0-9]-[0-9](",":[0-9]-[0-9](",df$COL1)`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
COL1 <- c("BLOC1.1_3_10-355(+)Sp_3",
"BLOC2.1_10-355(-)SSp_4",
"BLOC3.1_10-355(+)SP_32",
"BLOC1_3_10-355(+)SP4_2")

gsub( "(.*[0-9]+)(_)([0-9]+-.*)", "\\1:\\3", COL1)

[1] "BLOC1.1_3:10-355(+)Sp_3" "BLOC2.1:10-355(-)SSp_4"  "BLOC3.1:10-355(+)SP_32" 
[4] "BLOC1_3:10-355(+)SP4_2"
```

Answer (score 4):

You can use

```
_([0-9]+-[0-9]+\()
```

And replace with `:` and capture group 1.

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/hduwD5/1)

```
COL1 <- c("BLOC1.1_3_10-355(+)Sp_3", "BLOC2.1_10-355(-)SSp_4", "BLOC3.1_10-355(+)SP_32", "BLOC1_3_10-355(+)SP4_2")
gsub("_([0-9]+-[0-9]+\\()", ":\\1", COL1)
```

Output

```
[1] "BLOC1.1_3:10-355(+)Sp_3" "BLOC2.1:10-355(-)SSp_4" 
[3] "BLOC3.1:10-355(+)SP_32"  "BLOC1_3:10-355(+)SP4_2"
```

Answer (score 3):

A solution using string splitting:

```r
output <- sapply(COL1, function(x) {
    parts <- strsplit(x, "_(?=\\d+-)", perl=TRUE)
    paste(parts[[1]][1], parts[[1]][2], sep=":")
})
names(output) <- c(1:4)
output

                        1                         2                         3 
"BLOC1.1_3:10-355(+)Sp_3"  "BLOC2.1:10-355(-)SSp_4"  "BLOC3.1:10-355(+)SP_32" 
                        4 
 "BLOC1_3:10-355(+)SP4_2"
```

**Data:**

```
COL1 <- c("BLOC1.1_3_10-355(+)Sp_3", "BLOC2.1_10-355(-)SSp_4",
          "BLOC3.1_10-355(+)SP_32",  "BLOC1_3_10-355(+)SP4_2")
```